# Google chrome ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED using mkcert

Tags: https, localhost, mkcert

Environment

```
OS: MacOS 12.6
mkcert version: 1.4.4
Server: localhost
Client: Chrome 105.0.5195.125
```

What you did

mkcert -install
mkcert {$domainName}
What went wrong

Works well on firefox & safari but not on chrome when accessing my react app on $domainName:3000 using command line:

`HTTPS=true DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN=true SSL_CRT_FILE=~/Documents/$domainName.pem SSL_KEY_FILE=~/Documents/$domainName-key.pem npm run start`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found on some other post about meteor app.
Just prefix the command-line with `HOST=0.0.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to make my app work on chrome when disableing wifi on my laptop. It looks like chrome is trying to resolve from internet (and fails) before resolving from my localhost.